# Azure thinks authentication key is 1024 bits, but it's not

Tags: python, adal

I've been struggling to retrieve a token using the acquire_token_with_client_certificate function. No matter what I use for my PEM encoded key / cert, I receive the below error:

```
AdalError: Get Token request returned http error: 401 and server response: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50032: RSA key size 1024 is less than the minimum required 2048 bits.\r\nTrace ID: 32bf21de-e77a-4419-ab2b-cdc3a9343200\r\nCorrelation ID: 291050ae-0e86-4d09-bd62-7cfc53750db9\r\nTimestamp: 2018-04-16 13:51:50Z","error_codes":[70002,50032],"timestamp":"2018-04-16 13:51:50Z","trace_id":"32bf21de-e77a-4419-ab2b-cdc3a9343200","correlation_id":"291050ae-0e86-4d09-bd62-7cfc53750db9"}
```

My code is as follows:

```
def get_private_key(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as pem_file:
        private_pem = pem_file.read()
    return private_pem

context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority_url, api_version=None)
key = get_private_key('../keys/fullkey.pem')

token = context.acquire_token_with_client_certificate(
    resource_id,
    client_id,
    key,
    thumbprint_new)
print token
```

No matter which .pem file I point to (I've generated multiple in an attempt to debug), I continue to receive the same error.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Thank you,
Mike

Comment: Your RSA key is 1024 bits, the server requires a key of at least 2048 bits. You will have to create another valid key.

Comment: Here's the command I ran to generate my private key:

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f jwtRS256.key`

I send the resulting key to Azure, but I continue to receive the same response.

Answer (score 1):

This error is received because the RSA key size you are providing as an input is less than 2048. You will be able to solve this issue by increasing the key size to 2048 bits or more.

These are the steps to generate a private key file and a certificate which can be used for authentication in Adal python.

1. Generating a key: `openssl genrsa -out server.pem 2048`
2. Creating a certificate request: `openssl req -new -key server.pem -out server.csr`
3. Generating a certificate: 
   `openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.pem -out server.crt`

You will have to upload this certificate(`server.crt`) on your Azure Portal in the application settings. Once you save this certificate, the portal will give you the thumbprint of this certifcate which is needed in the acquire token call. The key will be the `server.pem` key you generated in the first step.